# Calculating the tip based on the condition and pushing it into a finalBill

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I Need to calculate the tip based on the condition and push it into the blank array, getting a parsing error.

```
var tipCalculator = {

    var billVal : [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    let finalBill :[],
    calcTip : function(){
        for(i =0; i<this.billVal.length; i++)
            {
                if(this.billVal[i] <50)
                    {
                        this.billVal[i] = this.billVal[i]*0.2;
                        this.finalBill.push(this.billVal[i]);
                    }
                else if(this.billVal[i] >= 50 && this.billVal[i] <= 200){
                    this.billVal[i] = this.billVal[i]*0.15;
                    this.finalBill.push(this.billVal[i]);
                }
                else if(this.billVal[i] > 200){
                    this.billVal[i] = this.billVal[i]*0.1;
                    this.finalBill.push(this.billVal[i]);
                }
            }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare object fields as a variables, so just remove let and var for field names

```js
var tipCalculator = {

  billVal: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  finalBill: [],
  calcTip: function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.billVal.length; i++) {
      if (this.billVal[i] < 50) {
        this.billVal[i] = this.billVal[i] * 0.2;
        this.finalBill.push(this.billVal[i]);
      } else if (this.billVal[i] >= 50 && this.billVal[i] <= 200) {
        this.billVal[i] = this.billVal[i] * 0.15;
        this.finalBill.push(this.billVal[i]);
      } else if (this.billVal[i] > 200) {
        this.billVal[i] = this.billVal[i] * 0.1;
        this.finalBill.push(this.billVal[i]);
      }
    }
  }
};

tipCalculator.calcTip()
console.log(tipCalculator.finalBill)
```

Comment: Did you do any other change, because I am still getting an error, 'i' is not define, even if I define i, it says,parsing error.

Comment: yes, i also add `let` key word to iterator in the loop: `let i = 0` @YAshrAj

Comment: sure I copied your code and still the parsing error. Did it run just fine for you? I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: @YAshrAj it works in snippet and in other playgrounds

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in strict mode and ran into the error that `i` was not declared.

```
const test = {
  billVal: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  finalBill: [],
  calcTip: function() {
// note the var, that was the parse error for me
    for (var i = 0; i < this.billVal.length; i++) { 
      if (this.billVal[i] < 50) {
        this.billVal[i] = this.billVal[i] * 0.2;
        this.finalBill.push(this.billVal[i]);
      } else if (this.billVal[i] >= 50 && this.billVal[i] <= 200) {
        this.billVal[i] = this.billVal[i] * 0.15;
        this.finalBill.push(this.billVal[i]);
      } else if (this.billVal[i] > 200) {
        this.billVal[i] = this.billVal[i] * 0.1;
        this.finalBill.push(this.billVal[i]);
      }
    }
  }
};

test.calcTip();
console.log(test.finalBill)
```

Comment: Do you have more code than just this? If you copy-and-paste the above code, do you still get an error? Finally, how are you running this code? If you are using a browser, try a different browser and see what it does.

Comment: this is it, the code. I am using dreamweaver and still getting the error, no matter if I declare i or not.

Comment: You may have better luck with codesandbox.io, codepen.io, or jsfiddle.net. Those sites all have great online editors for testing your code and surprisingly good tooling.(It would be nice if you upvote the two of us)